# Not able to open eclipse if Xmx is set to 2048

Tags: java

I am able to launch eclipse if I have below values in `eclipse.INI`

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

But I am not able to open eclipse if i have

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
```

My system configuration is

Windows 7 64 bit with 8 GB RAM

Comment: Have you look at the log? What are the errors? Put it on your question.

Comment: Substantiate "not able" to improve your chances of getting help. Open the eclipse log file and look for exceptions.

Comment: Perhaps you are running a 32 bit JVM - please investigate what kind of JVM you're running Eclipse under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your Java 32 or 64 bits?

32-bits JVM cannot allocate more than ~1,5GB of RAM. It because it has some problems with allocate continuous block of memory. 64-bit version dont have  this kind of problems.

Comment: When i checked with System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model") it says 32 Bit. Thanks I shall download 64 bit and try it out

Comment: With 32 Bit when i tried with -Xmx1500m its failing. So with Java 32 bit whats the maximum value i can give for Xmx??